# Javascript / jQuery Addition Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am working on a Javascript math game and could use some guidance. I need to create a 10 problem game that presents users with questions one at a time for simple addition. I started on something but am already running into trouble. I also need some way to present the users with the answers they got right and wrong in the end.

Any help available? It would be greatly appreciated.

I have included in the answer while I was working on it but obviously I need the user to submit the answer themselves and store that.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettlewis/hyqhD/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //declare arrays and variables for use below
    var pNum1 = new Array(); 
    var pNum2 = new Array();
    var pNumCarry=0;
    var pNumAns = new Array();
    var ans = new Array();
    var score=0;

    function pNumGen(x) { 
        pNum1[x] = (Math.round(Math.random()*51));
        pNum2[x] = (Math.round(Math.random()*51));
        pNumAns [x] = pNum1[x] + pNum2[x];
        $(".pNum1").html(pNum1[x]);
        $(".pNum2").html(pNum2[x]);
        $(".pNumAns").html(pNumAns[x]);
    }

    $(".Play").click(function() {
        pNumTrack = 0;
        pNumGen(pNumTrack);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like homework :)

Answer (score 0):

To get user input you may want to look at [window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt):

As for presenting the users with right/wrong answers in the end, is a very non-specific question and would depend on how you implement the rest of the game.
One possibility might be to use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) where you can push some text to after each guess, e.g. "Question #1: 15 + 39 = 105 - Incorrect", and then looping through and printing the array contents when the game is over.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just created little example how you can start to create your game:

http://jsfiddle.net/ePjGs/1/

```
$(function() {
    getQuestion();
});

var count = 0,    
    results = [];
function getQuestion() {
    count++;
    var container = $('<div />');
    var val1 = Math.round(Math.random()*51);
    var val2 = Math.round(Math.random()*51);
    var lbl = $('<label />');
    lbl.html(val1 + ' + ' + val2 + ' = ');
    container.append(lbl);
    var input = $('<input type="text" />');
    container.append(input);
    var btn = $('<input type="button" value="Submit result" />');
    var val;
    btn.click(function() { 

        results.push({
            number1 : val1,
            number2 : val2,
            answer : input.val()
        });

        input.attr('disabled', true);
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        $(this).after(function() {
            if(val1 + val2 == input.val()) return 'SUCCESS!';
            return 'ERROR';
        });

        getQuestion(); 

        updateResults();
    });
    container.append(btn);
    $('body').append(container);
}

function updateResults() {
    $('#json').html(JSON.stringify(results));
}
```